# Requesting new packages for inclusion on the CD

Tags: package-management, cd-image

There's a process for requesting new packages be [added to the archives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages), but I can't seem to find one that details how to request new packages be added to the CD. How would I go about requesting this?

Comment: I would guess most requests of this kind would have been suitable for discussion during the UDS. There should have been a session discussing the default packages and applications to be included for the forthcoming release in every UDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you discuss it in the Ubuntu Developer Summit([UDS](http://summit.ubuntu.com/)). They are responsible for what packages should come with the default ubuntu installation CD.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but I'd already found that page and it doesn't contain any information on requesting new package for inclusion on the CD.

Comment: Ravi, that is for requesting packages to be included in Ubuntu repositories and not for including packages by default. There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: Your call really. If I were you, I would try to fix my answer instead of deleting though.